# Did I misunderstood the AND query in Solr?

Tags: php, solr

I have two fields in a solr document, "title" and "subject" (both are available by default)

Then I place two rows in the database, and search on them.

But the AND query `title:"facebook" and subject:"java"` returns both the rows.

It should only return the second row, right?

```
<?php
   $solr = new SolrClient (array ('hostname' => '127.0.0.1'));

   /////// INSERT ////////
   if (0)
   {
      $data = array (
         array (
            'id'       => 100,
            'title'    => 'Google',
            'subject'  => 'Java Interface'
         ),
         array (
            'id'       => 101,
            'title'    => 'FaceBook',
            'subject'  => 'Not Java'
         )
      );

      foreach ($data as $input)
      {
         $doc = new SolrInputDocument();
         foreach ($input as $key => $value)
         {
            $doc->addField ($key, $value);
         }

         $solr->addDocument ($doc, false, 1000);
      }

      sleep (3);
   }

   /////// QUERY ////////
   $query = new SolrQuery();

   $query->setQuery('title:"facebook" and subject:"java"');
   $query->addField('id')->addField('title')->addField('subject');

   $resp  = $solr->query($query)->getResponse ();
   print_r ($resp->response->docs);
?>
```

Comment: `Not Java` has no logical meaning to Solr. It is just two words to Solr. At the query level you can get documents containing `title:facebook` and not containing `Java` in subject using `+title:facebook -subject:Java`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the `AND` keyword must be in uppercase.